# FOR loop in app.py just prints out last result. SQLAlchemy and Flask FOR Loop problem

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to show how much staff assigned for an upcoming Event.
For that I have a simple list with the eventname and the .count() of all the assignments from the specific event.

In the app.py I have the following code:

```
for single_event in list_events:
            croupier_assigned = assignments.query.filter_by(e_id=single_event.event_id, role="croupier").count()
```

In the .HTML File I have the following code:

```
{% for single_event in list_events %} 
{{single_event.eventname}} | {{croupier_assigned}} <br>
```

In the Browser it looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQBT5.png)

Now as you see, every Event has one assignment, but that's totally wrong. Further investigation, I found out, that it prints the LAST result from the query to every event:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6GT3.png)

It goes tru and prints for every event the last result from the query... Why doesn't it print the result from every event for the specific event itself? And how can I make it doing it what I want?

- Staff, Events and Assignments are different tables in one database)
- Assignments is connected with a ForeginKey to the Staff and Events tables (One to Many Relations)

Answer (score 0):

In the **App.py** I added following code (Added code is **Bold** / marked with two **):

```
list_events = events.query.order_by(events.eventdatetime).all()
**single_events_assignments=[]**
for single_event in list_events:
            croupier_assigned = assignments.query.filter_by(e_id=single_event.event_id, role="croupier").count()
            **single_events_assignments.append(croupier_assigned)**
```

in the **.html** file I changed it to:

```
{{single_event.eventname}} | **{{ single_events_assignments[loop.index0] }}** <br>
```

The "single_events_assignments" is a list Then for every Loop it adds the croupier_assigned count from the single_event to that List.